# CSS issues. Stop displacinng of the button

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I have some issues with a website of my business.

So I bought a theme for my website(Wordpress) and downloaded few extension to that, because it was included to the theme. Unfortunately I saw some issue, when I zoom out by my browser Chrome/Firefox, the right picture "Teilen" displace to the next line, and I want to force it to stay as it is by original one.

And here is the code:

```css
.products li.product.grid.with-hover .product-actions {
    top: 5px;
    left: 19px;
    right: 19px;
    padding-top: 13px;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    border-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="product-actions">
                        <a class="out-of-stock" title="Vergriffen">Vergriffen</a>            <a href="#" class="button yith-wcqv-button" data-product_id="2150">Quick View</a>                        <div class="buttons buttons_3 group">
                <a href="http://lockpick.ch/produkt/goso-kaba-deluxe-dietriche/" rel="nofollow" title="Details" class="details">Details</a>

<div class="yith-wcwl-add-to-wishlist add-to-wishlist-2150">
      <div class="yith-wcwl-add-button hide" style="display: none;">

         
<a href="/?add_to_wishlist=2150" rel="nofollow" data-product-id="2150" data-product-type="simple" class="add_to_wishlist" style="zoom: 1;">
        Wunschliste<div class="blockUI" style="display:none"></div><div class="blockUI blockOverlay" style="z-index: 1000; border: none; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; top: 0px; left: 0px; opacity: 0.6; cursor: none; position: absolute; background: url(&quot;http://lockpick.ch/wp-content/themes/bazar/theme/assets/images/ajax-loader.gif&quot;) center center no-repeat rgb(255, 255, 255);"></div><div class="blockUI blockMsg blockElement" style="z-index: 1011; display: none; position: absolute; left: 32px; top: 25px;"></div></a>
<img src="http://lockpick.ch/wp-admin/images/wpspin_light.gif" class="ajax-loading" alt="loading" width="16" height="16" style="visibility: hidden;">
     </div>

     <div class="yith-wcwl-wishlistaddedbrowse show" style="display: block;">
         <span class="feedback">Produkt hinzugefügt!</span>
         <a href="http://lockpick.ch/wishlist/view/">
             Wunschliste ansehen         </a>
     </div>

     <div class="yith-wcwl-wishlistexistsbrowse hide" style="display:none">
         <span class="feedback">Dieses Produkt ist bereits in der Wunschliste vorhanden.</span>
         <a href="http://lockpick.ch/wishlist/view/">
             Wunschliste ansehen         </a>
     </div>

     <div style="clear:both"></div>
     <div class="yith-wcwl-wishlistaddresponse"></div>
 
</div>

<div class="clear"></div>

<a href="#" class="yit_share share">Teilen</a>            </div>
                    </div>
```

**CSS issue**

[image]

**Website:** [www.lockpick.ch](http://lockpick.ch/)

Hope you can help me, because I am totaly newbie to CSS/HTML...

Greetings 
Lucia

Answer (score 1):

The issue comes from the use of a width of 33.3333% for these elements. While in most cases this approximation of 1/3 works, in some settings it ends up being problematic and the 3 elements end up being slightly more than 100% width.

A simple fix would be to edit this 33.3333% to 33%. Visually the users shouldn't see the 1% missing on the right and it solves your issue.

From the website link you provided, it is located in style.css line 675:

```
ul.products li.product.grid.with-hover .product-actions .buttons.buttons_3 > *, 
.product-box .buttons.buttons_3 > * {
        width: 33%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try so :) Because by default the box-sizing is content-box which is meaning width and height properties (and min/max properties) includes only the content. Border, padding, or margin are not included.

These element has border-left: 1px solid #e0dfdf; and width: 33.333%. In the smaller screen, each element will has small width, e.g less than 100px lead to 1px border costs more than 1% of width. Then the last element is pushed down to next line.

```
ul.products li.product.grid.with-hover .product-actions .buttons a.details, .product-box .buttons a.details {
   box-sizing: border-box;
}
```